# Auto select value from dropdown list using macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have thousands of records in a excel file and for each rows there is a dropdown list. I want to use a macro by which vue to dropdown lists will be selected based on certain criteria from each row. Please help me

Please help me. I have no idea

Comment: You mean there is data validation in the cells? Where is the validation list coming from? What are the criteria you mentioned? You can use someRange.Validation.Formula1 to get the range the list is specified in and then select the value from that but I have no idea if this is what you need.

Comment: My dropdown list has "yes" and "no". For each row of consumers there is a field called paid which has option to choose either yes or no. How to paid fields of all consumers automatically rather than manually choosing each dropdown lists?